# What is "on-topic" for Homework?

Tags: discussion, homework

Under the existing Asking policies, homework questions are acceptable as long as they have "`a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.`"

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782786/sql-query-maxsum-homework#27782786), which basically asked to verify/check a potential solution.  At the time, "homework" was part of the title.  Clearly the OP put some effort into it (and even came up with an answer), but the question itself asks "Is this the right answer?"  And of course the flip-side is if the answer is "no," there may be many solutions.  So is this question "on-topic" and if so is the attempted answer the reason it is?

Comment: The fact that the question is homework is irrelevant.  Treat it just the same way you'd treat the question if it wasn't homework.

Comment: You judge the question on the normal quality metrics, we generally *don't care if it is homework or not*.

Comment: Ok that seems reasonable.  Thanks.

Comment: We're not here to *do* people's homework, but that doesn't mean we can't help them with it.

Comment: Of course I didn't mean to imply that we shouldn't help with well-formed homework questions.  It was mainly the part of the question that basically asked "Is this the answer/Does this code work?" that confused me.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I get where you're coming from. Consider this. If the author had not included his SQL, this would be an "Answer my homework for me" question which would get downvoted away. Probably would have been better if the asker had said "I tried this, but it doesn't seem right" but the point comes across as the author put effort in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of a question is irrelevant, what matters is the content of the question. If 'homework' follows the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Then in my book, it's ok and I'll try and answer it. Most homework exercises are too broad to be a good SO question in their own right though. If someone's taken some time to write some code, and can supply a MCVE and a specific query... then that's fine.

If their post is 'please write me some code that fits this spec...' then I'll call it offtopic, regardless if it's homework, commercial or anything else.